# Gradient with a Shape

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, gradient

I need to create a background for an element that looks like the following

[image]

Is it possible to implement this with gradients or some other technique or will I have to use an image file?

It is only the background that I am having trouble with, not the drop shadow effect.

Comment: Are you trying to have that curve in the gradient? If not then absolutely, can show you how to do that real fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do it with just one Element, then something like;

```
<Border Width="300" Height="75"
                BorderThickness="3"
                CornerRadius="5">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C3C3" Offset="0.429"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE9E9E9" Offset="0.652"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE9E9E9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB9B6B6" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="280" Color="#FF515050" BlurRadius="2"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
```

If you want your curve in the gradient, then something like;

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="75">
        <Border 
                BorderThickness="3"
                CornerRadius="5">
            <Border.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFC4C3C3" Offset="0.429"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE9E9E9" Offset="0.652"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.Background>
            <Border.BorderBrush>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE9E9E9" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFB9B6B6" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Border.BorderBrush>
            <Border.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="280" Color="#FF515050" BlurRadius="2"/>
            </Border.Effect>
        </Border>
        <Path Data="M0,0 L300,0 L300,40.768158 L296.83832,41.189522 C253.5976,46.794456 203.45944,50.000004 150,50.000004 C96.540565,50.000004 46.402409,46.794456 3.1617098,41.189522 L0,40.768158 z" Fill="#FFDADADA" Margin="3" Height="50" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False"/>
        </Grid>
```

You'll of course need to play with your colors and sizes to get exactly what you want but this should hopefully be a good place to start for you. Cheers

Comment: The second part of your answer worked brilliantly, thanks a mill.

Comment: No worries, have a great weekend!